# Toolbar keeps hiding on Safari

Tags: macbook-pro, safari

I am trying to keep the toolbar visible all the time....when I select 'View' the 'Hide Toolbar' is grayed out.  My wife has the same machine, and her's has 'Hide toolbar' not grayed out which I assume she could select and would get the result I am getting.  Any help would be appreciated, it's getting annoying now.

Answer (score 2):

There is a preference for this - select View and select "Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen" option

Answer (score 1):

If you're in full screen mode, this behavior is normal (the hide toolbar option greyed out, not the lack of visible toolbar contents). If your not in full screen mode, then:

- Go to **View -> Customize Toolbar...**
- Then, perform the **"...drag the default set into the toolbar"** option.
- Now, go to the **View** drop down again and the Hide/Show Toolbar option should be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Go to View. Go to bottom. Exit full screen and resize the window to fit frame.

Answer (score 0):

For Macbook Air hold Alt/option key down while pressing green full screen button (top left on toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences - General - uncheck "automatically hide and show the menu bar.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score 0):

Your are in "full screen" mode.  Hit ESC and then resize your screen with your cursor and pulling edges with the arrow to your desired size.

Answer (score -1):

You are in "Full Screen" mode.

Hit "esc".